# Build process tools for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, build, continuous-integration

I am starting a new project - a reasonably large application - that features just JavaScript code (excepting a little HTML/CSS) and have been giving some thought to a suitable build process and the tooling options available. I'd love to hear from anyone who has had similar choices to make recently.

### Some requirements

I do have some essential requirements (I might add more bells and whistles later, but these are really necessary):
- **Minification of code**: I'd like the option to be really aggressive with this for staging/production builds (think [Closure Compiler with advanced optimisations](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html).)
- **Code quality checking**: [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or similar - something to throw up any glaring issues with the code.
- **Unit testing**: I have a very strong preference for [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) when it comes to unit testing JS - the ability to test multiple browsers simultaneously (and quickly!) and to automate easily are the main attractions. That said, I'd happily look into alternatives.
- **Continuous integration-friendly**: we make use of a CI server (BuildBot, for the record) and any build script(s) would have to be easily automated.

### Possible solutions

I've already thought of a couple of possibilities (some details are guesswork, do correct me):

#### Ant

**Pros**:
- Seems to involve the least work, not least because of the excellent [HTML5 Boilerplate build script](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Build-script) as a starting point
- Many tools are written (or have wrappers) in Java - including JSLint/Hint, Closure Compiler and JsTestDriver
- Ant scripts are standard fare when it comes to CI servers
- Happily cross-platform

**Cons**:
- Running many JAR files possibly a bit slow? (I'm thinking in terms of initialisation more than execution)

#### Ruby/Rake

**Pros**:
- (Well-written) Ruby scripts are quite probably nicer to deal with than piles of XML
- There are wrappers (often gems) for many relevant tools, such as [JSLint](https://github.com/psionides/jslint_on_rails), [JSTestDriver](http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/jstdutil_a_ruby_wrapper_over_jstestdriver) and [UglifyJS](http://rubygems.org/gems/uglifier)
- Equally cross-platform

**Cons**:
- Knowledge of Ruby involved to modify the build process. While this isn't a huge deal, we're not a Ruby shop and the alternatives don't have quite the same barrier to entry
- Few of the tools actually run in Ruby and are actually wrappers around Java or JavaScript code executing - this seems like it may slow things down

#### Node (and probably something like [Jake](https://github.com/mde/jake))

**Pros**:
- Plenty of tools available in JavaScript (and as modules available to Node) - JSLint/Hint, UglifyJS etc.
- Presumably pretty quick ([this blog post](http://badassjs.com/post/971960912/uglifyjs-a-fast-new-javascript-compressor-for-node-js) illustrates UglifyJS outpacing Closure Compiler quite comprehensively, for one)

**Cons**:
- Node (particularly NPM) doesn't seem quite there on Windows yet (we have some developers running Windows)
- There doesn't seem to be any existing support for using JsTestDriver from a Node app (but a wrapper could be written)

Based on that, Ant seems the favourite at present.

Comment: the html5 boilerplate build.xml isn't that great - you'll want to stay away from ant-contrib.  it's the quickest way to get a rat's nest of unmaintainable gunk.  I'd recommend you stay away from ant.   If you go that way -let ant be ant, don't try to make it feel like  a scripting language.

Comment: Maybe Gradle with some plugins ex. http://eriwen.github.io/gradle-js-plugin/ ?

Answer (score 5):

A brief follow-up now that the project is complete:

**Ant** was chosen to build the project, but later on I wished I'd used a Node-based solution. While you *can* make Ant do most things, it's often verbose or necessary to write a lot of Java code to make it do anything out of the ordinary. Node and NPM improved on Windows significantly throughout the lifetime of the project and there are now a surfeit of testing solutions ([BusterJS](http://busterjs.org/) is interesting me most) that can easily be called from a Node script.

I was intrigued to see the release of [Grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt), which seems like it could have been particularly useful for a project like this. I'd be keen to hear people's experiences of this tool used with projects of reasonable size (for reference, the project I have just completed had around 120 JavaScript source files.)

Answer (score 5):

Over a year later, but...

If r.js + RequireJS is your thing, and you want automated builds plus development aid/help like linting, minification, concatenation, asset compilation, etc, check out [Mimosa](http://mimosajs.com).  It'll do a lot of those things right out of the box with minimal configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for dependency management/dynamic script loading, and building a single file.
For continuous integration check out [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) from JetBrains.

Comment: RequireJS is definitely useful for managing dependencies and relationships between JavaScript files, but I was more interested in an overall build script or system that could make use of (for example) RequireJS's r.js optimiser.

Answer (score 1):

#### Gulp

There is a new build tool called **[gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)** that uses node streams, so it does not have to write any temporary files between steps (like grunt).  It's fast.